# Skip irelevant text from some of bars in plotly bar chart

Tags: r, plotly

I create a simple plotly bar chart but inside the first columns I get a weird text that I need to delete.

```
library(plotly)
sum2<-structure(list(month = structure(c(1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 
1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 
1475280000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    Monthly = c(14236.895, 4519.892, 55691.009, 28295.345, 23648.287, 
    34595.1276, 33946.393, 27909.4685, 81777.3508, 31453.393)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

fig <- plot_ly(sum2, x = ~month, y = ~Monthly, type = 'bar', text = text,
               marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                             line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)',
                                         width = 1.5))
)
fig <- fig %>% layout( width=1800,height=600
)

fig
```

Comment: remove `text = text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you were doing with `text = text` but just remove that line and it looks fine.

```r
plot_ly(
  sum2,
  x = ~ month,
  y = ~ Monthly,
  type = 'bar',
  # text = text,
  marker = list(
    color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
    line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)',
                width = 1.5)
  )
)
```

[image]

---

This happens because `text` is referring to the function `graphics::text()` and when called without parentheses it just gives the report of that object with that name. Try just running `text` at the console (without parentheses) and you'll see what was getting passed as labels to your plot.

```r
text
#> function (x, ...) 
#> UseMethod("text")
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000013994f20>
#> <environment: namespace:graphics>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>